# Modify text with jQuery for dynamically added elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page http://www.projectdemocracy.in/ where some elements are dynamically added (example - CSS class ".fyre-comment-count" showing "X Comment").

I wanted to modify the text once page is loaded.

I was able to change the text using console of jQuery

```
$(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations");
```

When I type the same in my page, it doesn't work.

I also tried `$(document).ready(function(){});` but no luck (same with document.ajaxSuccess).

Similarly, document.on would be working only with 'click' events but I want it to be done by default.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fyre-comment-article', function() {
     //Code
    });
```

Does it have any 'load' type event in document.on?

What should I do to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: when you typed it into your page and didnt work did an error show up in your console?

Comment: No, no error in the console!

Comment: Saw your site, and noticed that the background didn't stretch. Maybe it is an idea to implement the background-size: cover CSS trick?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed your web page and saw the following code:

```
var articleId = fyre.conv.load.makeArticleId(null);
fyre.conv.load({}, [{
    el: 'livefyre-comments',
    network: "livefyre.com",
    siteId: "351251",
    articleId: articleId,
    signed: false,
    collectionMeta: {
        articleId: articleId,
        url:  "http://projectdemocracy.in",//fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl(),
    }
}], function() {});
```

It seems like the 3rd argument of `fyre.conv.load` method is a callback function that will be executed when all elements are generated.

So put your code inside this function. It will be like this:

```
...
}], function() {
    console.log('callback');
    $(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations");
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

If it still doesn't work it may be because livefyre runs this callback *before* DOM elements are being created. The workaround is to put `$(".fyre-comment-count").html(...);` inside `setTimeout` with minimal delay:

```
...
}], function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations");
    }, 10);    //minimal delay. wait till livefyre generates all needed elements
});
```

**EDIT 2**

This is another variant how to make it work:

```
...
}], function(widget) {
  widget.on('commentCountUpdated', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations");
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

This widget has a `commentCountUpdated` event, so you have to subscribe on it, and every time the comments number is changing, your callback will be executed

By the way, `commentCountUpdated` callback recieves a single argument - the number of comments, so you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
}], function(widget) {
  widget.on('commentCountUpdated', function(commentsNum) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".fyre-comment-count").html(commentsNum + " Conversations");
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not working with current setup. Will it only work when url parameter is set to be "fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl()"?

Comment: @user3234684 I don't know. It's just a code that I found on your page

Comment: @user3234684 I edited my post (added `console.log`). Can you see "callback" in your console after that?

Comment: Hey, I am getting the callback but $(".fyre-comment-count").text() returns empty!

Comment: @user3234684 try to put to the callback function:
    `setTimeout(function() {
      alert($(".fyre-comment-count").length)
    }, 10);`
what do you see in alert? Or try to increase the delay from 10 to 50

Comment: On page load, it shows the "X Conversations" as expected but changes back to "X Comments" after some time!

Comment: @user3234684 if livefyre updates this label after some time, you may put your code in `setInterval`, although it's a very bad practice (and label will blink). It would be great if we find the way how we can customize this label with their API, but I can't find how it can be done. If it's not possible with their API, I would recommend to give up and not to use dirty hacks (`setInterval`), if it's possible to you

Comment: @user3234684 take a look at my edit 2. I think now it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a on load event, if this is what you are looking for:

```
$(window).load(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: I had tried "$(document).load(function(){$(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations")});" but it pulls complete page and doesn't change the text.

Comment: Fixed, forgot to change to window.

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? $(window).load(function(){$(".fyre-comment-count").html($(".fyre-comment-count").text().split(" ")[0]+" Conversations")}); doesn't work!